# how to move the jslider on pressing mouse on jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jslider

I have two jbuttons (left and right on jslider) and one jslider.

On pressing mouse on left Jbutton, jslider needs to be move towards left.

On pressing mouse on right Jbutton, jslider needs to be movew towards right.

Please help me how can i solve this.

Thanks
Jyoti

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.htmlBlockquote), all you need to do is to use `setValue(int)`

void setValue(int)

Sets or gets the slider's current value. The set method also positions the slider's knob.

I am assuming that you mean moving the actual pointer not the entire component itself. If you want to move the entire JSlider, you should use the `.setLocation(int x, int y)` method.

Edit: It depends what you need to do. If you want to move the slider programmatically, you might want to put a Thread.sleep(timeout) so that the thread pauses for some time allowing you to see the slider moving. On the other hand, you can make the slider move one single time each time the button is pressed, for instance, each time the 'Left' button is pressed, the slider's value is decreased by 10. The opposite happens for the right button. The latter seems to be the most widely used (to my knowledge at least) approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the setValue() method of JSlider on mouse press event of Jbutton. I have used while loop to decrease or increase the value. JSlider is moving really fast not with the normal speed as the jslider moves. Could you please suggest me something over it?

Answer (score 2):

[`JSlider#setValue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setValue%28int%29) is used to set the sliders position to value. The value should be in the range between (including) `JSlider#getMinimum` and `JSlider#getMaximum` and the slider will take care of converting the value to a "pixel-position".

---

Edit - you can introduce delays with `Thread#sleep`. You just need to "wait" some milliseconds before you send the next "setValue" message to the JSlider:

So while the button is pressed, you're in a loop:

```
while(isPressed) {
  adjustSliderByOneTick();
   try { 
     Thread.sleep(100);  // 100 milliseconds for a first test
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     break;
   }
}
```

If the button is released you set the `isPressed` flag to `false` and the above loop ends.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the setValue() method of JSlider on mouse press event of Jbutton. I have used while loop to decrease or increase the value. JSlider is moving really fast not with the normal speed as the jslider moves. Could you please suggest me something over it?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might take a look at [`SpinSlider`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970073), which combines `JSlider` and `JSpinner`. It also works nicely with the keyboard, and it adjusts to the user's preferred keyboard repeat rate on most platforms.