# Movable bars with value using java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

I want to create a bar with a value. If i move the circle, then the value in the field should change. How can i do this?
Here is the screen shot. How can i achieve this?

Something similar to this is also ok. Please help me with this.
Thank you in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`SpinSlider`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969233/javaswingmvc-how-to-make-a-model-that-interfaces-w-multiple-controls/1970073#1970073) may be a useful example.

Addendum: Here's an example using a suitable format string for `JSpinner.NumberEditor`.

Addendum: You can change the color of the slider by overriding `paintTrack()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898023/custom-java-swing-meter-control/2898259#2898259).

[image: SpinSlider image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067898 */
public class SpinSlider extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("SpinSlider!");
                f.add(new SpinSlider());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public SpinSlider() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        final JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSlider s = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                spinner.setValue(s.getValue());
            }
        });
        this.add(slider);
        spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100, 1));
        spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner, "0'%'"));
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSpinner s = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
                slider.setValue((Integer) s.getValue());
            }
        });
        this.add(spinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SRIKANTH KV: I saw your followup question and addressed the issue above.

Answer (score 5):

To create a bar with a value (slider) in Java, you can use the `JSlider` class. When you create an instance of this class you can specify all the parameters like min. and max. value, step size, etc.

You can add a `ChangeListener` to the slider. This `Changelistener` should implement the method `stateChanged()` and in this method you can change the value displayed in the text box based on the position of the slider.

```
JSlider slider= new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,100,50); //min value 0, max value 100, initial value 50
slider.addChangeListener(this)
JTextFox text = new JTextFox("50");
//Some other code, adding the the slider, text box (and other stuff) to the application
//...

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{
   JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
   int value = (int)source.getValue();
   text.setText(Integer.toString(value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java Swing you could use a [JSlider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html) (which already has the desired model and behavior) and then customize its UI