# how to add an event to my slider code

Tags: java, swing, jslider, changelistener

How can I add an event to this code such that if i drag the slider, the number is displayed. Please, let me know as I am new to Java..

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Slider extends JFrame {

    JSlider pickNum = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 30, 5);

    public Slider() {
        super("Slider");
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pickNum.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        pickNum.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        pickNum.setPaintTicks(true);
        pickNum.setPaintLabels(true);
        getPointedValue();
        this.add(pickNum);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public final int getPointedValue() {
        int value;
        value = pickNum.getValue();
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Slider frame = new Slider();
        int i;
        i = frame.getPointedValue();
        System.out.println("current value is:" + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use Java reserved words as class names use MySlider instead of Slider, don't extends JFrame because this is direct road to the problems, GUI rellated code in the main void should be wrapped into invokeLater, for more read [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a concrete example using `ChangeListener`, [`SpinSlider`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067986/230513) shows how to connect a `JSlider` and a `JSpinner`.

[image: Spin slider]

Answer (score 5):

See [`addChangeListener(ChangeListener)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#addChangeListener%28javax.swing.event.ChangeListener%29), as well as [How to Use Sliders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) & [How to Write a Change Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html).

Comment: @henry joseph maybe important, maybe not, you have look at `BoundedRangeModel` and add `ChangeListener` to this model